# JVM max heap size parameter not working while instanciating it through C++

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-arguments

I am creating instance of JVM through C++. I am  passing a couple of VM parameters while instantiating. But at least one of the parameter for max heap size is not showing any difference. The max heap size always shows 65 536kB what ever parameter I provide for it.

The code is as shown below.

```
    jvm=NULL;
env=NULL;
long result;
char *pathname=(char*)malloc(1024);
strcpy(pathname,"-Djava.class.path=");  
strcat(pathname,"/*class path*/");


vm_args.version= 0x00010006;  
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized=JNI_TRUE;
options[0].optionString=pathname;
options[1].optionString="-Xms512M";
options[2].optionString="-Xmx1024M";
vm_args.options=options;
vm_args.nOptions=3;
```

Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please feel free to ask if the question is not clear enough. thanks in advance.

Comment: possible value of the classpath option is not properly set... try to play with order of options

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matters, but in my code, I use a lower case 'm' at the end:

-Xmx1024m

instead of

-Xmx1024M

that's the most obvious difference between your code and what we use...

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the heap size increase when instantiating this way. I mean when instantiating from C++.

Comment: At this point, this feels to me like something simple like an array not getting initialized properly (or maybe the options array isn't the right size??).  Something like that.  it may be advisable to post more of your code - strip it down to the absolute minimum code that can recreate the problem. We initialize JNI like this all the time with no issues, so it's unlikely to be a JVM problem.